# Area Settings for Wacom (Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, tablet, wacom

So I just installed Lubuntu yesterday and everything has pretty much gone smoothly without an major problems. I really am enjoying the speediness of this OS over Windows. I just have this on small problem.

So initially I set the area of the Wacom tablet using xinput and setting the area in the QTerminal and it worked fine. I also did the same for the touchpad on the laptop. The problem is that, when I rebooted the comp the next day, all the changes I have made didn't seem to save at all.

So after some searching I decided to edit the 40-libinput.conf file and the 70-wacom.conf file. I've managed to properly setup my touchpad, but I'm unsure about what I need to add to the 70-wacom.conf file to properly set the area.

I've searched this site and many others and I can't seem to find the option for it. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

I believe I need to add "Option" into this section. Maybe "Option "Area" "100"" or something along those lines.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Wacom USB tablet class"
    MatchUSBID "056a:*"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsTablet "true"
    Driver "wacom"
```

Comment: Can you please add release info; you mention `qterminal` so it's likely you're talking about 19.10, but that clarification maybe helpful for future people. Thanks  (if 19.10 it'll likely work perfectly with 20.04)

Comment: Apologies. It is 19.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I've done some searching around and I've found the solution. You need to add:-

```
Option "TopX" "0"
Option "TopY" "0"
Option "BottomX" "21600"
Option "BottomY" "12150"
```

I chose those values to force set the tablet's resolution to match the aspect ration of the monitor and it works fine. Also you need to use nano or any editor of your choice given that you need permissions to edit the file.